# Como apagar a imagem original após o crop?

Tags: wordpress

Através da área *media* do Wordpress, é possível adicionar imagens.

O problema é que o cliente não sabe recortar as imagens utilizando um programa de edição, como o *Photoshop*, então ele utiliza a ferramenta de *crop* padrão do *Wordpress*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto ao gerar o *crop*, a imagem original é mantida, o que é um problema uma vez que essas imagens geralmente possuem mais de 5MB.

**Como apagar a imagem original após recortar a imagem?**

Comment: Apagar somente o arquivo jpg/png? Ou de alguma forma todo o `attachment`?

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma possível é usar a action [`wp_ajax_crop_image_pre_save`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_crop_image_pre_save/) pra substituir a imagem original pela imagem recortada, algo assim:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_crop_image_pre_save', 'sobrescrever_imagem', 10, 3 );

/*
 * Busca a imagem original e substitui pela imagem recortada.
 * atualizando os meta-dados
 */    
function sobrescrever_imagem( $context, $attachment_id, $cropped ) {
    // Busca os metadados originais  
    // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/
    $orig_data = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id );

    $orig_data['file'] = $cropped;

    // Gera novamente os metadados
    // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/
    $updated_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $cropped );

    // Salva no attachment original
    // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_attachment_metadata/
    if ( wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $updated_data ) ) {

        // Deleta o original
        $orig_file = $orig_data['file'];
        unlink( $orig_file );
    }
}
```

**esse código não foi testado**, é so um caminho pra começar. Tem mil coisas que podem dar errado aí no meio, porque mídia no WP é complicado mesmo.

Comment: Olá Ricardo. Obrigado pelo seu tempo. A solução não funcionou. Continua a gerar uma nova imagem e a manter a original.